# Setting Angular Material 2 theme to dark theme

Tags: angular, themes, angular-material

I recently created an Angular Material 2 app by following this [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started). Now I want to know how can I change the theme to dark or `dark-theme`?

Comment: https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app might help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add following CSS in your style.css file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';

// NOTE: Theming is currently experimental and not yet publically released!

@include md-core();

$primary: md-palette($md-deep-purple);
$accent:  md-palette($md-amber, A200, A100, A400);

$theme: md-light-theme($primary, $accent);

@include angular-material-theme($theme);

$dark-primary: md-palette($md-pink, 700, 500, 900);
$dark-accent:  md-palette($md-blue-grey, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    md-palette($md-deep-orange);

$dark-theme: md-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
```

P.S. https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app/blob/master/src/material2-app-theme.scss

Comment: It's not working because language of above code is scss not css.

Comment: @mojtab23 there is no support for variables in CSS (atleast widely). SCSS is the only way to override CSS.

Comment: Yeah that's the correct answer. You need to use SCSS to build your custom theme, or you need to use a prebuilt dark theme.

Comment: Change md-xxx to mat-xxx in material latest version! Example: md-palette is now mat-palette...

Answer (score 3):

As of current release: 2.0.0-beta.3, add bellow to your global `sass` file.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
// Plus imports for other components in your app.

// Include the common styles for Angular Material. We include this here so that you only
// have to load a single css file for Angular Material in your app.
// Be sure that you only ever include this mixin once!
@include mat-core();

// Define the palettes for your theme using the Material Design palettes available in palette.scss
// (imported above). For each palette, you can optionally specify a default, lighter, and darker
// hue.
$dark-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$dark-accent:  mat-palette($mat-amber, A200, A100, A400);

// The warn palette is optional (defaults to red).
$dark-warn:    mat-palette($mat-deep-orange);

// Create the theme object (a Sass map containing all of the palettes).
$cdark-theme: mat-light-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

// Include theme styles for core and each component used in your app.
// Alternatively, you can import and @include the theme mixins for each component
// that you are using.
@include angular-material-theme($cdark-theme);
```

[More details](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md)